# Force The Encrypted Disk 'To Ask For Password', If User Tries To Format

Tags: encryption, formatting

I've been trying to encrypt a disk with BitLocker, but the issue is it only asks for password for unlocking it. Which means anyone can format that disk, & it doesn't even ask for password. Is it possible that if a user tries to format encrypted disk, he's prompted for a password?

If not in BitLocker, can this feature be enabled in linux?

Comment: Encryption is to protect your data from unauthorized acces not from protecting your disc from being formatted

Comment: theoretically you could tweak a system to do this.  but what happens when that computer is rebooted to a live USB/CD, or the protected drive is removed and put into another computer? your tweaks are gone, and the drive can be formatted as-is.

Comment: I've answered, but I feel like you've got an issue you're not actually asking about - the 'solution' for a formatted disk is good known backups.

Comment: BitLocker's for windows, doesn't windows ask for an "administrator password" or "root password" before formatting hard drives/partitions? Or are you running Linux, and just want to try someone from erasing a particular hard drive? In win or linux, a root user can basically write to anything. There are very expensive hardware based security drives that won't let anyone do anything without the correct password, some will even self-destruct under the right conditions (enter wrong password too much, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Not by any means I currently know of.

You'd basically need an interface directly to the disk itself, which requires the password to format (or write as we could just write 0's to the entire disk).

As this doesn't exist currently, for any hard disks then it's impossible. Another way to think about the problem is, what happens when you take the disk out of computer A, and put it into the computer B? This shows the functionality must exist on the hard drive itself, and none currently offer this.

Comment: You're right, it simply isn't possible. You can always just erase a drive anytime.